# jq - How to Left Join and merge fields from two input JSON files

Tags: json, join, merge, left-join, jq

I have two JSON files that I want to merge together, keeping all records from the first file and merging in the fields from the second file based on a matching key field value.

I'm using the `jq` command-line tool on Linux to do this.  The latest version of `jq` that I can use is: `jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe`

Here are my input files, and the JSON I'm trying to generate:

**Input File #1:**
`input1.json`

```json
[
  {
    "id": "item1",
    "join_id": "123",
    "field1": "val1",
    "field2": "val2"
  },
  {
    "id": "item2",
    "join_id": "123",   // Same join_id as above
    "field1": "val1",
    "field2": "val2"
  },
  {
    "id": "item3",
    "join_id": "456",
    "field1": "val3",
    "field2": "val4"
  },
  {
    "id": "item4",
    "join_id": "789",   // Not found in lookup JSON
    "field1": "val5",
    "field2": "val6"
  }
]
```

**Input File #2:**
`input2.json`

```json
[
  {
    "joinId": "123",
    "joinField1": "AAAAAA",
    "joinField2": "BBBBBB"
  },
  {
    "joinId": "456",
    "joinField1": "CCCCCC",
    "joinField2": "DDDDDD"
  }
]
```

**Desired Output:**

```json
[
  {
    "id": "item1",
    "join_id": "123",
    "field1": "val1",
    "field2": "val2",
    "joinId": "123",
    "joinField1": "AAAAAA",
    "joinField2": "BBBBBB"
  },
  {
    "id": "item2",
    "join_id": "123",
    "field1": "val1",
    "field2": "val2",
    "joinId": "123",
    "joinField1": "AAAAAA",
    "joinField2": "BBBBBB"
  },
  {
    "id": "item3",
    "join_id": "456",
    "field1": "val3",
    "field2": "val4",
    "joinId": "456",
    "joinField1": "CCCCCC",
    "joinField2": "DDDDDD"
  },
  {
    "id": "item4",
    "join_id": "789",
    "field1": "val5",
    "field2": "val6"
  }
]
```

It's also OK if the `joinId`, `joinField1`, `joinField2` fields get added to the "item4" record, as long as they have `null` or empty string values.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jq 1.6 you would just employ `INDEX` and `JOIN`:

```bash
jq '[JOIN(INDEX(input[]; .joinId); .[]; .join_id; add)]' input1.json input2.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IkniZigFMX1)

For a jq 1.5 solution you could just grab the definitions of those two builtins from the [Github Repository](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq) and re-implement them within your code:

```bash
jq '
  def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
    reduce stream as $row ({}; .[$row|idx_expr|tostring] = $row);
  def JOIN($idx; stream; idx_expr; join_expr):
    stream | [., $idx[idx_expr]] | join_expr;
  [JOIN(INDEX(input[]; .joinId); .[]; .join_id; add)]
' input1.json input2.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/QcksU0mnA7x)

But then, you could also multiply out those two definitions to directly fit your use case:

```bash
jq '
  (reduce input[] as $row ({}; .[$row.joinId] = $row)) as $idx
  | map(. + $idx[.join_id])
' input1.json input2.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/KIDuoLcn476)

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "item1",
    "join_id": "123",
    "field1": "val1",
    "field2": "val2",
    "joinId": "123",
    "joinField1": "AAAAAA",
    "joinField2": "BBBBBB"
  },
  {
    "id": "item2",
    "join_id": "123",
    "field1": "val1",
    "field2": "val2",
    "joinId": "123",
    "joinField1": "AAAAAA",
    "joinField2": "BBBBBB"
  },
  {
    "id": "item3",
    "join_id": "456",
    "field1": "val3",
    "field2": "val4",
    "joinId": "456",
    "joinField1": "CCCCCC",
    "joinField2": "DDDDDD"
  },
  {
    "id": "item4",
    "join_id": "789",
    "field1": "val5",
    "field2": "val6"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is awesome!  Thank you so much for the quick reply on this @pmf.  I've been fighting with this all morning, and this does exactly what I need.